# html5 file image in draggable div throws SecurityError: The operation is insecure

Tags: jquery, html, fileapi

I have an html div in which an image inserted, that was locally inserted:

```
 <div class="box ui-resizable ui-draggable box-selected" id="box8" style="word-wrap: break-word; outline: 0px solid transparent; font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; position: absolute; width: 151px; height: 113px; display: block; left: 151px; top: 227px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-align: center;" aria-disabled="false">
 <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
 </div>
```

Before I insert the image, it is no problem to drag the (jquery ui draggable) div, but after the image is inserted by javascript file api, I get an `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.` and dragging on this div stops working. What can I do?

Comment: jsfiddle code would help to understand more

Comment: This is not jqueryui-related. Any uncaught error stops javascript execution (which the draggable callbacks rely on)

Comment: of course, but that does not say its not jqueryui-related

Comment: in jsfidle it works unfortunately. Must have a different cause.